# Google Play without credit card processor. Possible?

Tags: google-play

we have problem with a bank, and can not sign a contact for a credit card processing. 
As I understood from Google documentation we MUST have a payment gateway to earn money on Google Play?

e.g. there no internal account like on PayPal or App Store

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question - it is a question about google's policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no such thing as you describe for the Google Play store.

I think the only option is to fix the problems with the bank.